# Interactively highlight nodes and edges in igraph

Tags: python, igraph, graph-drawing

In the networkx library is possible to click on a node and hi-light it and it’s edges.

This page illustrates this solution:
[Interactive networkx](https://networkx.github.io/grave/latest/gallery/node_picking.html). This is a desktop-based solution.

I tried to find a similar solution for the igraph library but I can't find it.

Currently, I use d3 and sigma.js for this purpose. But I'm interested in a desktop-based solution, similar to the above mentioned for the networkx library.

Does anyone know any desktop-based solution for interactively highlight nodes and edges using igraph library?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: igraph uses Cairo as a backend (or at least it used to when last I checked the code base), which does not support interactive drawing (AFAIK). A short google search however revealed that [there may be workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031689/2912349).

Comment: Thanks for your replay!